# pbcopy via shell_exec() not working with native PHP installed in MAC Sierra by default

Tags: php, macos, terminal, macos-sierra, pbcopy

I want to copy some text sent by browser to clipboard after making changes using PHP and I can do that with PHP installed via AMPPS or XAMPP but when I try it with PHP which comes by default on Sierra I'm neither getting any error message nor the text is getting copied to clipboard.

This is the code I'm using

```
shell_exec("echo 'Any random text' | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy");
```

I tried changing permissions of PHP file, ensured that code works in terminal. I tried giving absolute paths like

```
shell_exec("/bin/echo '$text ' | tr -d '\n' | /usr/bin/pbcopy");
```

I ensured safe mode is not enabled because I get output "_www" for this code

```
echo shell_exec("whoami");
```

Still I cannot copy the text. Out of limitations I have to use only default PHP in sierra. Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: The first command worked fine for me on Sierra.

Comment: Are you using default PHP version installed with Sierra ?

Comment: Yes, which is PHP 5.6.30.